# WooCommerce Subscription: Don't have the SUSPEND button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

On my account page / View subscription, in the ACTION paragraph, I have a CANCEL button but not the SUSPEND button. Do you know if it is normal?

I have traced this function and it returns only the cancel data : wcs_get_all_user_actions_for_subscription

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal Pipoo.

There is an admin setting that allows suspend/suspend options.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/store-manager-guide/#misc-settings

I figured this out the hard way myself.

Its possible you may need to update as well if your version of subscriptions is old/outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `WooCommerce` **>** `Settings` **>** `Subscriptions`

Update the value of *Customer Suspension* from zero to the limit you want.

[image]